# FIX: failed to select a version for the requirement `<crate = "version>"`

Tags: upgrade

documenting an error and a fix for others. While updating a substrate repository I was getting an error:

```
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `wasmtime = "^0.38.0"`                                                                      
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.37.0, 0.36.0, 0.35.3, ...
```

Checking crates.io I could see that there was a valid release for this crate and version, however, cargo was failing to find the latest version but there is a simple fix.

**Fix**

Remove cargos existing artifacts for the targeted directory: `cargo clean`
Then `cargo check` will be able to get the latest versions of crates.

Comment: You should split the answer here into an answer, not embedding it into your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove cargos existing artifacts for the targeted directory: `cargo clean` Then `cargo check` will be able to get the latest versions of crates.