# failed to select a version for the requirement wasmtime

Tags: cargo

I have the same problem of [this post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/fix-failed-to-select-a-version-for-the-requirement-crate-version) but `cargo clean` and `cargo check` doesn’t fix it.

This is my terminal output:

```
Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement wasmtime = "^0.38.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.37.0, 0.36.0, 0.35.3, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package sp-wasm-interface v6.0.0 (/substrate/primitives/wasm-interface)
```

**Update**

`rustup show` output:

```
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/*****/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)
```

Comment: You must have given different version of the dependencies, just the versions and delete cargo.lock file and then build it.

Comment: I tried to delete cargo.lock but didn't work. I don't know I see wasmtime version 0.38.0 on creates.io

Comment: And cargo find it if I search with `cargo search wasmtime` first result `wasmtime = "0.38.1 # High-level API to expose the Wasmtime runtime`

Comment: You need to match all the dependencies version, it should be same. Your cargo is finding `wasmtime = 0.38.1` but it needs a lower version of wasmtime.

Comment: Yes I know, in the `Cargo.toml` I have `wasmtime = 0.38.0` but form the output of my terminal it seems cargo can't select this version.

Is it correct? sorry I'm new with Rust

Comment: please include the result of `rustup show` and ideally your repo.

Comment: I add the `rustup show`, for the repo I just clone this one https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update rust toolchain with command `rustup update` fixed the issue.

You could also try clean the registry index by remove folder `~/.cargo/registry/index` if you don't want to update the toolchain.

Comment: It works, thank you!